# Apply css styling to a single DT datatable

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I have a pair of DT datatables in my shiny app. I would like to control the width of one of these tables (via fixed-width) while leaving the width of the other table dynamic.

After trialing a number of approaches for fixing columns widths, the one that seems best for my application is to use the styling `table.dataTable {table-layout: fixed;}`. However, this effects both tables.

How can I limit the effect of this style to just the second table?

```r
data(starwars)
starwars = starwars[1:5,1:4]

ui = fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("variable_width"),
  tags$style(HTML("table.dataTable {table-layout: fixed;}")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("fixed_width")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  output$variable_width = DT::renderDataTable({ starwars }, options = list(dom = "t"))
  output$fixed_width = DT::renderDataTable({ starwars }, options = list(dom = "t"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

From searching, it looks like this should be possible via `div`: That you can limit styling to only the current div. However, I am unable to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add what are the parents div in you CSS, like this :

```
tags$style(HTML("#fixed_width > .dataTables_wrapper > table.dataTable {table-layout: fixed;}")),
```

With `#fixed_width` being the outputId (which is also a div id) of you second table.